the_title and document_title in a single call are causing issues on menu items
I'm trying to replace the_title and document_title on dynamic pages like ?filter=most-viewed, it works but only problem is the menu items are getting replaced with custom title too.
add_filter( 'document_title', 'custom_title', 10 );
add_filter('the_title', 'custom_title', 10);

I don't want to write 2 functions for each call so my function is:
function custom_title( $title ) {
  $filter = $_REQUEST['filter'];
    if($filter=='most-viewed'){
      $title = 'Most Viewed';
    }

//Fix issue in the loop
    if (in_the_loop() ){
    global $wp_query;
      return $wp_query->post->post_title;
    }
      return $title;
}

I tried to add below code but does not work
    if (is_nav_menu() ){
    global $wp_query;
      return $wp_query->post->post_title;
    }

If I add all function inside if (in_the_loop() ){ it resolves the issue on menus but the document_title won't work.

Within the callback, you can add remove_action( current_action(), 'custom_title', 10 ), limiting each action to running only once.
